# Avatar upload during register. D6

Tags: users

It is possible upload a avatar during the registration process? Then save it into the profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used it before but the [Register with Picture](http://drupal.org/project/reg_with_pic) module sounds like it would do the trick:

> This module exposes the 'upload picture' element to the registration form. It also gives you the ability to set a picture as required in the module settings.

There are stable versions for both Drupal 6 and Drupal 7. It also has 1600+ installs, is actively maintained and has very few issues in the queue, so I'm assuming it should work great.